# Delphi перемещение кнопки

Tags: delphi

```
unit U6_2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Button1.Left:= 0;
Button1.Top:=0;
Form1.Color:=clRed;

end;
end.
```

Что нужно прописать чтобы при втором щелчке на кнопку она оказалась в правом верхнем углу и чтобы она изменила свой размер?

*Обновление*

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if n=0 then
  begin
    Button1.Left:= 0;
    Button1.Top:=0;
    Form1.Color:=clRed;
    n:=1;
  end
  else
  begin
    Button1.Width := Button1.Width * 2;
    Button1.Height := Button1.Height * 2;
    Button1.Left:= ClientWidth - Button1.Width;
    Button1.Top:=0;
    Form1.Color:=clGreen;
    n:=0;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Хочу сделать так чтобы при третьем щелчке на кнопку форма оказалась в правом нижнем углу и чтобы при четвертом щелчке форма оказалась в левом нижнем углу. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

попробуй поставить флажок:

```
if flag=0
then begin
flag:=1;
...
end else begin
flag=0;
...
end;
```

Или используй Tag у button - не придется переменную создавать)

*Обновление*

```
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    case n of
        0:  begin
            Button1.Left:=0;
            Button1.Top:=0;
            Form1.Color:=clRed;
            n:=1;
            end;
        1:  begin
            Button1.Width:=Button1.Width * 2;
            Button1.Height := Button1.Height * 2;
            Button1.Left:= ClientWidth - Button1.Width;
            Button1.Top:=0;
            Form1.Color:=clGreen;
            n:=2;
        2:  begin
            ...
            n=3;
            end;
        3:  begin
            ...
            n:=0;
            end;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: @Luchfan12 т.е. 4 клика и 4 местоположения кнопки?

Comment: И будет кнопка по кругу бегать)

Comment: Получилось!